# How to copy several rows between two equal tables with JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Is there a way to do something like

```
INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...
```

with JPQL? Both tables are structurally equal, so that I defined two entity classes which inherit all field mappings from a superclass. The two `@Entity` subclasses differ only in their names and `@Table` annotations.

We use JPA 2.0 and Hibernate 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String hqlInsert = "insert into DelinquentAccount (id, name) select c.id, c.name from Customer c where ...";
int createdEntities = s.createQuery(hqlInsert).executeUpdate();
```

See here for more information
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct

Comment: If you're using Hibernate then you can use HQL. There may not be a JPA equivalent.